# base64 encoded pdf string breaks api

Tags: php, json, post, base64

I have POST request which contains a json with a base64 string which represents a pdf, this requests fails and I am trying to figure out a solution to it.

I thought it was just encoding it using url_encode but then it seems to lose part of the data when i decode it.

I tried using PHP json encode from the array but same issue.

It might be that the string is more than 25000 chars long but not sure. if someone have ever encountered this issue and have a solution please share it

```
$pdf = (isset($params['pdf']) && $params['pdf'] != "" ? $params['pdf']  : null);
```

Please find below a sample of the payload

https://pastebin.com/JK8zTsAG

NOTE: they keep removing my pastebin -

```
{
    "id":"5555555",
  "pdf": "7CfNe3nszmfAFMOAc3jgsgTMGEfDIMQzCxTvwAMIwgtUKEy9ikGKGCR6fN8LMmj"
}
```

The above works well but if I add the real pdf base64 string it breaks since its over 20k long.

In short :
I am receiving the payload in the pastebin, it contains a base64 string which represents a pdf but when I receive the pdf string (which is really long over 20k characters) it breaks the api.

Comment: You say: _"I have POST request"_, and I am trying to figure out if you mean that you are posting data to somewhere, or you are receiving data from somewhere. Can you tell me which one it is?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/VsUxvq4u

Comment: I am receiving the payload in the pastebin, it contains a base64 string which represents a pdf but when I receive the pdf string (which is really long over 20k characters) it breaks the api.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/VsUxvq4u also only gives _"This page is no longer available. It has either expired, been removed by its creator, or removed by one of the Pastebin staff."_

Comment: they keep removing my paste bin - I have updated the ticket with more insight 
@CBroe

Comment: Maybe you simply have a problem with `post_max_size` being set too low, or something like that? It is really hard to tell, when you just show us one line of code, and with no indiciation whatsoever, where `$params` does even come from.

Comment: I guess that what you call _"the api"_ is your PHP code. You say that the pdf string _"breaks the api"_. What does the latter mean? Do you get an error message? From your question I cannot tell whether it is the length of the incoming data, or the handling of data itself, that is problem.